# PHP server download file from url fails without logging errors and downloads file partially

Tags: php, error-handling, fopen, file-get-contents, error-reporting

I'm trying to download a from into the server from a url, but the file is partially downloaded and I get a server error with no specific errors showing to debug.

**The PHP code is as follows.**

```
if (!isset($_GET['url'])){
    die('set file url');
}

if (empty($_GET['url'])){
    die('file url cannot be empty');
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
set_time_limit(3600000);

$file_url       = $_GET['url'];
$ext_array      = explode('.', $file_url);
$extention      = end($ext_array);
$new_file_name  = "file".time().rand().".".$extention."";

file_put_contents($new_file_name, fopen($file_url, 'r'));
```

As on the code, I tried turning error reporting ON and also made a php.ini on the server but no errors are shown nor logged into an error log file.

Also I'm on shared hosting.

**MORE INFO**

The file i'm trying to download is about 1.5 Gigs, and only ~125MB is being downloaded before the error.

Comment: Did you change the the max file size allowed by the server? See this QA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: @Terminus there's "upload_max_filesize" which is set to 2M and opcache.max_file_size set to zero. The upload fails at 125MB is already greater than these, do you think these might play a role in this?

Comment: Yes. Read the link. There are 2 directives that matter. Change those to atleaat 1.5GB.